# scala - mock function and replace implementation in tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using scalatest and when I test my code, I want to replace an implementation of a function to return something else when running tests.

In JavaScript its really simple and I thought I could do the same in scala.
So what I want is something like this:

```
object Module {
  private def bar(): Int = {
     5
  }

  def foo(): Unit = {
    println(bar())
  }
}
```

And the test will be something like that (dont mind the syntax, you get the idea)

```
class Test extends FunSpec {
   mock(Module.bar, () => 1)
   describe("Test") {
      it("Test") {
         Module.foo() // will print 1
      }
   }
}
```

I have searched the internet and came across scala mock libraries but none of them seemed to be able to replace the implementation of a method.
In every library you have to defined your mock in the test and pass it on to the code, but I don't want to do that.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock `Object` in Scala, because it's like a static class in java (which you can't mock either). (and you can't mock scala objects not in [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) nor [scalamock](http://scalamock.org/) (maybe in their next version)).

But, if you change your `object Module` to `class Module`, you can mock this function easily (using mockito):

```
val mockModule = mock[Module]
when(mockModule.bar()).thenReturn(1)
```

Comment: its still not what I want, I dont want to create an instance of the class Im mocking in my tests. My main method is using a function from an object/class and I want to mock that function, I can't pass the main method an instance of a mock.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a fake class that has that function and put the value you want, if you dont want to use mocks, like this:

```
trait SMT{
 def bar: Int
}

class RealImpl extends SMT{
def bar: Int = 5
}

class FakeImpl extends SMT{
def bar: Int = 1
}
```